# Как верстать, чтобы высота изменялась пропорционально изменениям ширины?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

```css
Сброс настроек*/

*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
} 

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 сброс отображения для старых браузеров */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/*НАЧАЛО*/
html {
 font-size: 100%;
}

body {
 background: orange;
 height: 100%;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
}

.wrapper {
 background: #336633;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 320px;
 max-width: 640px;
 height: 30rem;
 min-height: 480px;
}

/*ВЕРХНЯЯ СЕКЦИЯ*/
.top {
 height: 8.846153846153846%;
/* height: 50px;*/
/* height: 3.125rem;*/
 background: rgb(47, 47, 47);
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(54, 54, 54) 0, rgb(54, 54, 54) 50%, rgb(47, 47, 47) 50%, rgb(47, 47, 47) 100%);
 padding: 5.6px 0 5.6px 8px;
}

/*1-ряд верхней секции*/
.topone {
 width: 14%;
 height: 3rem;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1%;
}

.topone p {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30%;
 left: 20%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.topone img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.toptwo {
 display: table;
 float:right;
 width: 85%;
 /*height: 50px;*/
 height: 3.125rem;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.toptwo p{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.toptwo p span{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: rgb(255, 0, 42);
 text-transform: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

/*ВТОРАЯ СЕКЦИЯ*/
.middle {
 background: url(img/middle/Layer9.png) no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
/* background-size: cover;*/
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 width: 100%;
/* height: 275px;*/
/* height: 18rem;*/
height: 77%;
}

/*Ряд с градиентом*/
.middleone {
 width: 100%;
 background: url(img/middle/2.1/Layer8grad.png) no-repeat;
/* padding: 1.8125rem 2.25rem 1.75rem 2.4375rem;*/
  background-position: center;
 padding: 0.7rem 0 0.3rem 0;

}

.middleone p {
 /*font-size: 30px;*/
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 font-weight: 400;
 width: 75%;
 float: left;
 background-size: red;
 margin-left: 3%;
}

.middleone img {
 height: 1.4rem;
 width: 9%;
 margin-right: 1%;
}

/*Ряд с кнопкой смотреть*/
.middletwo {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.middletwo input {
 margin-top: 4.5rem;
 width: 65%;
}

/*Ряд с количеством просмотров */
.middletree {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.middletree p{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0.1em;
/* margin-top: 7.352941176470588%;*/
 font-size: 1rem;
 color: rgb(186, 186, 186);
}

/*Ряд с кнопкой отмена*/
.middlefour {
 text-align: center;
}

.middlefour button{
 margin-top: 0.5rem;
 border: 2px solid rgb(145, 146, 153);
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: 200;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 border-radius: 5%;
 background: rgb(13, 13, 23);
 opacity: 0.7;
}

/*ТРЕТЬЯ СЕКЦИЯ*/
.bottom {
 width: 100%;
 height: 17.11538461538461%;
}

/*Плеер*/
img[alt="player"] {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*Чекбокс*/
.bottomtwo {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
/* padding: 1.5625rem 2.0625rem 0.6875rem 1.25rem;*/

}

.wrapcheckbox {
 width: 15%;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
/* padding: 0.4rem 0rem 1.5rem 0.5rem;*/
}

.wrapcheckbox .checkbox{
 width: 1.3125rem;
 height: 1.3125rem;
}

.wraplabel {
 float: right;
 text-align: left;
/* margin: 0.25rem 2.5rem 0rem 1.0625rem;*/
/* padding: 32px 73px 18px 0px;*/
/* padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.25rem 0;*/
 width: 85%;
}

.wraplabel label {
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}

.wraplabel label span {
 font-size: 0.9rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 background: none;
}

/*Нижний ряд*/
.bottomtree {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.bottomtree {
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: rgb(164, 164, 164);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VideoTube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tablet.css" media="all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" media="all and (min-width: 769px)">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- ВЕРХНЯЯ СЕКЦИЯ  -->
            <div class="top">

        <!-- 1-ряд верхней секции -->
                <div class="topone">
                    <img src="img/top/12+.png" alt="age">
                    <p>12+</p>
                </div>

                <div class="toptwo">          
                    <p>video<span>Tube</span></p>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        <!-- Конец верхней секции -->

        <!-- ВТОРАЯ СЕКЦИЯ -->
            <div class="middle">

        <!-- Ряд с градиентом -->
                <div class="middleone">
                    
                    <p>Видео HD</p>
                    <img src="img/middle/2.1/time.png"  alt="time">
                    <img src="img/middle/2.1/links.png"  alt="links">.
                   
                </div>
        <!-- Конец ряда с градиентом -->

        <!-- Ряд с кнопкой смотреть -->
                <div class="middletwo">

                    <input type="image" src="img/middle/2.2/button!!!.png" alt="Watch"> 

                </div>
        <!-- Конец ряда с кнопкой смотреть -->

        <!-- Ряд с количеством просмотров -->
                <div class="middletree">
                    <p>Просмотров: 14204</p>
                </div>
        <!-- Конец ряда с количеством просмотров -->

        <!-- Ряд с кнопкой отмена -->
                <div class="middlefour">
                    <button>Отмена</button>
                </div>
        <!-- Конец ряда с кнопкой отмена -->

            </div>
        <!-- Конец второй секции -->
        
        <!-- ТРЕТЯЯ СЕКЦИЯ -->
            <div class="bottom">
        <!-- Плеер -->
                <img src="img/bottom/player.png" alt="player">
        <!-- Конец плеера -->
        
        <!-- Чекбокс -->
             <div class="bottomtwo">

                <div class="wrapcheckbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="check">
                </div>

                <div class="wraplabel">
                    <label for="check">Подтверждаю, что люблю мультики, и соглашаюсь с <span>правилами предоставления услуги</span></label>
                </div>

            </div>   
        <!-- Конец чекбокса -->
        <!-- Нижний ряд -->
             <div class="bottomtree">
                <p>&nbsp;Услуга: domainname.eu. Провайдер ООО "Эс Эм Экс Комьюникейшнс". Стоимость 20 руб в сутки с НДС. </p>
            </div>
        <!-- Конец нижнего ряда -->
            </div>
        <!-- Конец третий секции -->

        </div>
        <!-- Конец -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать, чтобы высота изменялась пропорционально изменениям ширины ?

Например нужно сверстать макет плеера у которого минимальный размер `320px/480px`. На всех разрешениях плеер должна помещаться в 1 экране (без горизонтального и вертикального скролла). Весть текст, кроме панели управления плеера должен меняться (т.е. не изображением).

Сам плеер – это пустышка, реализовывать функционал воспроизведения видео не нужно. Максимальная ширина – `640px`.

Плеер сверстал, но не знаю как сделать чтобы менялся в соответствии с требованиями.

Comment: покажи что уже готово

Comment: куда скинуть код, который уже готов  ?

Comment: например сюда, чтобы сразу было видно, что есть (тут можно сниппеты добавлять)

Comment: )) сори, я не совсем знаю, что такое сниппеты ?)

Comment: седьмая иконка слева в редакторе, на ней что-то вроде листочка и `<>`, ее жмешь и откроется окно куда можно ввести разметку, яваскрипт и css

Comment: я вставил, но тут выходит без картинок, потому как они в папке... может мне лучше на мыло скинуть или в скайпе, всю папку чтобы удобнее было  ?

Comment: картинки как-то влияют на верстку?

Comment: не влияют, но так наверное удобнее смотреть ) наверное это я думаю из-за недостатка знаний )

Comment: чем отличаются: _style.css_, _tablet.css_, _other.css_ и какой из них в примере добавлен?

Comment: Выкинтье из примера всё лишнее, что не относится к собственно вопросу. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent{
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.child{    
    padding-bottom: 66.67%;
    background: #ccc url('http://image.zn.ua/media/images/original/Jun2015/118798.jpg') no-repeat center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Пример для видео

```css
.parent{
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
.child{    
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 66.67%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.child iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/URwP6WkFu70" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял, как сделать чтобы изменялось пропорционально!
а как сделать, чтобы вертикальный скрол не выскакивал ?